# Django REST Framework Serializer - how to save InMemoryUploadedFile to disk?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

At my Django RestAPI I can upload an image, instead of saving this image at an ImageField referenced at the database I just want to save it to the disk without any further processing.
Currently, my code looks like this:

```
class UserAvatarUpdateSerializer(ClearNullSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    avatar = serializers.ImageField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'avatar',)
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'user')
   
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        new_avatar = self.validated_data['avatar']  
        directory = (str(MEDIA_ROOT) + "tmp/")
        filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
        new_avatar.save(os.path.splitext((directory + filename))[0] + '.png', optimize=True, format='png')
```

But I'm running into:

> AttributeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save'

So my question is how can I save a InMemoryUploadedFile to disk?

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick:

```
...
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        new_avatar = self.validated_data['avatar']
        new_avatar = Image.open(new_avatar)
        directory = (str(MEDIA_ROOT) + "user_avatar/")
        filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
        new_avatar.save(os.path.splitext((directory + filename))[0] + '.webp', optimize=True, format='webp')
```